# WPF ListBox ItemsContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, mouseevent

I have a strange problem with ItemsContainerStyle. I defined two different styles for ItemsContainerStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="LeftAligned">
  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="FullSelectionBox">
  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

During runtime I change the styles:

```
LogViewer.ItemContainerStyle = (Style) FindResource ("FullSelectionBox");
```

or

```
LogViewer.ItemContainerStyle = (Style) FindResource ("LeftAligned");
```

After I change the style, the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, PreviewMouseRightButtonUp or PreviewMouseUp event doesn't fire in the correct way. In most of time it is Russian roulette if the event comes up or not.

Any ideas why my application has this strange behaviour?